# Zapier change quantity on line item to 0.30 from 1.0

Tags: zapier

I have the attached Zap setup on my Zapier account and I need to change the quantity line for each line item to be 0.30.  Can this be hard coded somehow?

At the moment the quantity is showing as 1.0 on each line item (1.0,1.0).  We need to dynamically change the quantity to always be 0.30 for each line item.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way of doing this is by using a zapier code step. Write a generic Loop to run through the line-items and assign the number to the list of your new line-item variable. e.g

```
for (let i = 0; i < lineitem.length ; i++) {

    lineitem[i]=0.3

}
```